# How to check npm package name availability after new package moniker rules?

Tags: node.js, npm

Situation: now npm have [New Package Moniker rules](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/168978377570/new-package-moniker-rules) so we can't publish package with name, that is 'too similar' to existing packages. For example, we can't publish package with name 're.quest', cause package 'request' already exists. `npm publish .` will fail with error.

Unfortunately, we also can't check availability of package name until we try to publish it.

`npm search re.quest` will not tell us about 'request' package or any other reason to treat name 're.quest' as unavailable.

Tool [npm-name-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/npm-name-cli) will say '✔ re.quest is available'.

But it is not.

Question: is there any way to check **real** availability of npm package name without trying to publish it? Any npm command, CLI tool, npm site API or anything else?

Comment: Docs for [`npm search`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/search) state: _"If a term starts with /, then it's interpreted as a regular expression"_. My initial thought, (given your example), is do a `npm search` with a regex something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/ZO7kOA/1) (Note: that probably needs further escaping  via shell - I haven't tried it). However this assumes dots, dashes, and underscores are the only patterns npm compares against to police _typosquatting_. Their rules for this don't seem to be fully documented anywhere. E.g. Is plural impermissible too i.e. `requests`

Comment: @RobC, I know this trick with regexps, but it doesn't work good. For example `npm search /re[\.\-\_]*?quest/` returns `re-quests` but not `request`.

Comment: Download npm registry _(approx 64Mb of JSON)_ from CouchDB and query it locally. Steps: **1.** `curl -X GET https://replicate.npmjs.com/_all_docs > /path/to/db.json`. **2.** Install [json](https://github.com/trentm/json) which is a fast CLI tool for working with JSON. **3** Query/cat JSON file locally and filter with grep. E.g. `cat /path/to/db.json | json -a rows | json -a id | grep -E "^[_\.\-]*?n[_\.\-]*?o[_\.\-]*?d[_\.\-]*?e[_\.\-]*?j[_\.\-]*?s[_\.\-]*?$"` . **Results:** _node-js_, _node.js_, _node_js_, _nodejs_. Agreed, it's not elegant and entails downloading 64Mb regularly.

Comment: @RobC, thanks! Works much better then nothing despite slow download.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm surprised that npm don't seem to offer a solution for this. Their `npm search <regex>` is poor. B.t.w, using redirection instead of `cat` for that command in my previous comment should reduce the query time by a few seconds. E.g. `(json -a rows | json -a id | grep -E "^[_\.\-]*?n[_\.\-]*?o[_\.\-]*?d[_\.\-]*?e[_\.\-]*?j[_\.\-]*?s[_\.\-]*?$") < /path/to/db.json`

Comment: @RobC, I thinking about this in js-way: `require('./db.json').rows.map(v => v.id).filter(/* magic there */);` and cron-download. It almost comfortably. And yes, sometimes npm is not good )

Comment: Can't believe there isn't an easy answer to this :(

Comment: There is the  `validate-name` package as described in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665491/npm-publish-got-package-name-too-similar-to-existing-packages#answer-65370667) - haven't yet tried it myself.

Answer (score 3):

The best option is `npm view`:

- if the name is already taken, you'll get details of the package:

[image]

- if the name is up for grabs, you'll get 404 error:

[image]

Comment: For "re.quest" we can get 404, but it is NOT valid (because "request").

Answer (score 1):

use `npm search`

for example:

```
PS C:\Users\ashkan nasirzadeh> npm search bable
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
bable                     |                      | =sebmck         | 2015-02-16 | 1.0.1    |
bable-import-style-suffix | Modify the suffix…   | =mi_huan        | 2020-08-21 | 1.0.0    | change import path suffix
@kuddai/logonce           | Sometimes you wish…  | =kuddai         | 2020-06-27 | 1.0.0    | logging bable-plugin
jsmp-infra-nik-package    | my HW6 for Module2   | =nik_shaposhni… | 2020-04-01 | 1.0.4    | node scripts bable
bable-plugin-runmap       | show your code…      | =horve          | 2020-08-04 | 0.0.1    |
miaow-babel-parse         | Miaow的Babel编译工…  | =anhulife       | 2017-04-01 | 2.1.0    | miaow bable es2015 es2016 jsx
@58fe/bable-plugin-p5-imp | 针对p5组件库的按需…  | =liuhanbing…    | 2019-08-01 | 1.1.0    | 58 p5 vue 按需加载 vue-components ui
ort                       |                      |                 |            |          |
@oneisland/babler         | The perfectly…       | =larkin-nz      | 2019-11-08 | 0.0.9    | babler babel module-resolver oneisland
vinus4                    | Vinus is an…         | =usamaxyz       | 2020-05-28 | 1.0.3    | bable typescript gulp browserify watchify less sass rtl minify concat es6
bs-node-hello-world       | A Hello World…       | =albsugy        | 2017-07-02 | 0.0.1    |
vinus                     | Vinus is an…         | =usamaxyz       | 2018-11-06 | 1.3.8    | bable typescript gulp browserify watchify less sass rtl minify concat es6
rupert-plugin-babel       | Rupert…              | =davidsouther   | 2015-06-05 | 0.0.1    | rupert config esnext babel
@jarzzzi/nidavel          | ## 特性： - 支持…    | =jarzzzi        | 2020-04-07 | 1.0.6    |
@owo/owo                  | 1.…                  | =puge           | 2020-08-02 | 1.2.62   |
bable-loader-ymh          |                      | =jerryfishymh   | 2019-10-25 | 3.0.0    |
bable-plugin-transform-co | Babel preset to…     | =gyweqq         | 2018-12-25 | 1.0.0    |
py                        |                      |                 |            |          |
node-bb                   | Simple node bable…   | =crashbell      | 2017-01-21 | 2.0.11   | node babel boilerplate
@nolwenture/enumify       | This simply removes… | =zanitius…      | 2018-06-17 | 1.0.3    |
bable_es6                 |                      | =lapido         | 2017-08-10 | 1.0.15   |
babel-plugin-project-rela | A Bable plugin for…  | =gavriguy       | 2015-11-07 | 2.0.3    | babel babel-plugin
tive-require
```

if your package name hasn't been used yet you will encounter sth like:

```
PS C:\Users\ashkan nasirzadeh> npm search phpAPI                                                                                                                     
No matches found for "phpAPI"
```

more information about this command is available [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/search)

Comment: It doesn't work for 'too similar' names. Only for exact matches.