# npm publish got package name too similar to existing packages

Tags: npm

I want to publish my package to npm. the error I get is: Package name too similar to existing packages

```
403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/mypack.... - Package name too similar to existing packages; try renaming your package to '@user../mypackage...' and publishing with 'npm publish --access=public' instead
```

but when I try to install:

```
npm I mypackage...
```

I get the error not found:

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mypackage... - Not found
```

Is there a way to check if the name is good for npm and not just guess? because I can't delete the package after I publish..

Comment: Maybe a scoped package will help https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages

Comment: AFAIK npm [still does not provide a tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50508511/how-to-check-npm-package-name-availability-after-new-package-moniker-rules). I `curl` data from; `https://replicate.npmjs.com/_all_docs` _(approx 124Mb JSON)_ then query the `.json` file using [this](https://paste.ee/p/DdxFJ) custom nodejs script. Via the CLI I run: `node ./path/to/pkg-name-check.js "<pkg-name>"`. The rules for what is considered _"similar to existing pkgs"_ [is not fully documented](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/168978377570/new-package-moniker-rules), however the script is a good indicator.

Comment: @RobC, do you have any idea author of the script. I want to credit him/her in the module I created.

Comment: @ozm - I was the author of [this script](https://paste.ee/p/DdxFJ). Is that the one you're referring to?

Comment: @RobC. Yes, I used RegExp from that script in my open source module. I would like to add credits linking to your profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611459/robc . Also since I don't know that you are the author, I couldn't get permission to use it. Is it OK to use it in the module suggested below?

Comment: @ozm - yes of course it's OK to use it (or any part of it) in your module - thank you for asking.

Comment: Thanks @RobC, I added credits in source code and README.md. Also I will appreciate if you check the module.

Comment: @ozm -Just realized I've been using this [revised script](https://paste.ee/p/5kHBy) recently. The main notable difference in the revised script v's the [previously posted script](https://paste.ee/p/DdxFJ) is in the logic for how the regexp pattern is constructed (see changes made on lines #44 to #50 in the revised script). To demo the issue with the previously posted script try checking for the pkg name; `react.native` - it incorrectly reports [this list](https://paste.ee/p/ns5eg) of similar names. The revised script now correctly reports just [these similar names](https://paste.ee/p/qct4g).

Comment: @RobC, many thanks again. I updated module as you suggested.

Answer (score 6):

To check **similar names** you can use [validate-name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-name):

### Install:

```sh
$ npm install -g validate-name
```

### Use:

```sh
$ validate-npm-name my-module
```

```sh
$ validate-npm-name my-package --max-age 1440
```

### What it does:

This command checks whether similar names exist in npm registry.

Upon first use, it downloads full list of module names (apprx. 150MB as of this writing) to check similarity. Subsequent downloads are much smaller, because it only downloads updates since last download.

I created this module by following script suggested by @RobC in OP's comments. It is open source (MIT).

As described in the original script, it is a best effort, because similarity rules are not formally documented by npm.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior has been documented on the npm blog under [**New Package Moniker rules**](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/168978377570/new-package-moniker-rules):

> We’ve recently made some changes to how package naming works to better fight typosquatting, and help package authors pick names that stand out.
>
> If you are publishing a new package—that is, a package that has not been in the registry before, we remove punctuation from its name and compare it to existing package names. ***If the names are identical without punctuation, we do not allow the package to be created***.
>
> Because `react-native` exists, no one can publish variations like:
>
> - `reactnative`
> - `react_native`
> - `react.native`