# Npm error Package name too similar to existing packages

Tags: node.js, npm, module, package

I was publishing the npm module and I got an error

I verified my package name does not exist in the npm registry

403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/package - Package name too similar to existing packages; try renaming your package to '@name/package' and publishing with 'npm publish --access=public' instead

I wanted to know what factors npm filter the package and verify the names

Comment: See [Package Moniker rules](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/168978377570/new-package-moniker-rules) in the npm blog.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665491/npm-publish-got-package-name-too-similar-to-existing-packages/65370667#65370667

Comment: **See Also**: [npm publish got package name too similar to existing packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60665491/1366033)